# How can i import a func from another script in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-15

I am trying to import a function from another script in odoo but when i run the odoo its returning me a error. After i refresh website its working okay. But when i run the odoo every time i have this error.

this is error

```
assert module.startswith('odoo.addons.'), \
AssertionError: Invalid import of custom_addons.invoice_integration.models.model.InheritAccountMove, it should start with 'odoo.addons'. - - -
```

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from .xml_generator import start
from .bifatura_methods import send_invoice
from .numeric_to_string_price import numeric_to_string_price

from odoo import models, fields, api, SUPERUSER_ID, _
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError, QWebException
from odoo.addons import decimal_precision as dp
```

this is how i am using the imports.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the import the error is mentioning. Are you sure you've posted all the affected code?

Comment: its giving error cuz of                          from .xml_generator import start
            from .bifatura_methods import send_invoice
               from .numeric_to_string_price import numeric_to_string_price            it says      AssertionError: Invalid import of custom_addons.invoice_integration.models.model.InheritAccountMove, it should start with 'odoo.addons'. - - -